# Бот выходит сам при кике пользователя

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
import json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import time
import random

token = "tok"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


def kick_user(user_id):
    vk.method("messages.removeChatUser",{'chat_id' : 59, 'peer_id' : 2000000000 + 59,'user_id' : id,'member_id' : id})
# if user_id == admin_id and mess_user = 'kick':

# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():


    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:

            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text
        if event.from_chat:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id

            # Каменная логика ответа
            if request == 'Привет':
                kick_user(event.user_id)
```

Всё работает отлично. Но бот когда кикает пользователя который написал "привет", так же выходит с беседы. Почему?
[image: как то так]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, но вылезла другая ошибка(её уже решил).
Если написать
user_id = event.user_id
он не будет видеть какой ид надо кикнуть
if request == 'Привет' and user_id != bot_id:

По этому в первом и втором надо было заметить на просто id, без user
id = event.user_id
if request == 'Привет' and id != bot_id:
И работает отлично, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы бот не кикал самого себя, достаточно добавить простую проверку:

```py
import vk_api
import json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import time
import random

bot_id = 123122143 # айди вашего бота
token = "tok"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


def kick_user(user_id):
    vk.method("messages.removeChatUser",{'chat_id' : 59, 'peer_id' : 2000000000 + 59,'user_id' : id,'member_id' : id})
# if user_id == admin_id and mess_user = 'kick':

# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():


    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:

            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text
        if event.from_chat:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            user_id = event.user_id

            # Каменная логика ответа
            if request == 'Привет' and user_id != bot_id:
                kick_user(event.user_id)
```

Comment: Исправил, но вылезла другая ошибка(её уже решил). Если написать user_id = event.user_id он не будет видеть какой ид надо кикнуть if request == 'Привет' and user_id != bot_id:

По этому в первом и втором надо было заметить на просто id, без user id = event.user_id if request == 'Привет' and id != bot_id: И работает отлично, спасибо большое

Но можно вопрос, возможно ли сделать так, что если игрок с определенным доступом напишет слово допустим +kick, админ кикнет того пользователя на которого он указал? 
И как сделать. Будет время помогите, пожалуйста. А так спасибо большое)

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то выберете его верным здесь)

Comment: Что такое дм). Я на сайте можно сказать от силы неделю. не знаю многое

Comment: Можете написать мне в tg - mazzz3r